# Compare two dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I Want to comparing two dataframe columns and thier values. If it matches then it Shall be 1 and if not then 0.

How can i do this.? The dataframe has all the same column name. I need to check whether the values are matching or otherwise.

Comment: What is the dataframe in your context? Pandas?

Comment: Dataframe consist of data in number and char.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using pandas. In your particular case you can do this:

```
#Setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [5,4,2,6,1,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [3,4,0,6,1,5]})

#Relevant code
(df1["col"] == df2["col"]).astype("int8")
```

Output

```
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
Name: col, dtype: int8
```

Comment: I have a csv file and data from sql.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `df1` and `df2` as the target dataframes & `col` as the column of interest.

```
import pandas as pd 

def match_columns(df1, df2, col):
    match_list = [] 
    data1_list = df1[col].tolist()
    data2_list = df2[col].tolist() 

    for i in range(len(data1_list)):
        if str(data1_list[i]) ==  str(data2_list[i]):
            match_list.append(0) # matching values marked as '0'
        else:
            match_list.append(1) # non-matching values marked as '1'
    return match_list


if __name__ == "__main__":

    df1 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv1', header=0) # row 0 => column headers
    df2 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv2', header=0) # row 0 => column headers

    match_list = match_columns(df1,df2, 'TV1')   # match_list for 'TV1'
    print(match_list)
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but ending up in error,  showing name 'TVS1' is not defined.  I have chosen 'TVS1' as column name to compare between two dataset. Both the dataset with name df1 and df2 has the column 'TVS1' with the same values.  I just need to compare and mark the matching values as '0'  and if non matching then it Shall be marked as '1'

Comment: Are you defining the 'header' value when you load your csv into df? Please check my edits

Comment: No i am not defining header values. Also the header in both the files are the same. I just need to check whether the values in the columns are matching or otherwise. If it is matching then it should be flagged as '0' and non matching then '1' . For instance,  dataset df1 has columns TV1,TV2,TV3 with number values, similarly for df2 has the same columns with different values somewhat similar to df1.

Comment: Please try to run the code exactly as I suggested, and it should then give you what you need.